# searching specific fields in the rows in a file

Tags: bash, shell

i have a file which contains data like :

```
0000380000000101
0000650000000201
0000650000000301
0000650000000401
0001000000000101
0001000000000201
```

....and so on. i want to process this data, so that i get the output like

```
000065 0000000201 0000000301 0000000401  
000100 0000000101 0000000201
```

As 000065 repeated thrice, in the output i want 000065 to appear only once, while the corresponding bytes in each entry wherever 000065 occurred should be printed. Since, 000038 came only once, i dont want this in output. In this example, data (ie 000065 or 000038 happens to be 3 bytes, though it can be of any length while the bytes after this like 0000000401 will be of fixed length ie 5 bytes). i want to do this preferably using shell scripting or c. please let me know how can i do this. can awk be helpful here ?
any help will be greatly appreciated. Following is the data taken from actual file, i want to process:

```
0000000000000101
0000000000000201
0000000000000301
0000000000000401
0000380000000101
0000650000000201
0000650000000301
0000650000000401
0001000000000101
0001000000000201
0001000000000301
0001000000000401
0038d30000000101
00652e0000000201
00652e0000000301
00652e0000000401
008d750000000101
008d750000000201
008d750000000301
008d750000000401
0100010000000101
0100010000000201
0100010000000301
0100010000000401
01008d0000000101
01008d0000000201
01008d0000000301
01008d0000000401
01a8c00000000101
01a8c00000000201
01a8c00000000301
01a8c00000000401
0264010000000101
0264010000000201
0264010000000301
0264010000000401
0615df0000000101
0615df0000000201
0615df0000000301
0615df0000000401
07dd940000000101
07dd940000000201
07dd940000000301
07dd940000000401
0900000000000101
0900000000000201
0900000000000301
0900000000000401
15dfc70000000101
15dfc70000000201
15dfc70000000301
15dfc70000000401
1ecf090000000101
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (is sed OK?):

```
sed ':a;$!N;s/^\(.*\)\(\( *.\{10\}\)*\)\n\1/\1\2 /;ta;/ /!D;s/.\{10\} / &/;P;D' file
000065 0000000201 0000000301 000000401
000100 0000000101 0000000201
```

Answer (score 4):

Your data is fixed-width, so you can use `gawk`:

```
$ gawk -v FIELDWIDTHS='6 10' 'NR!=1 && x==$1""{printf(" %s", $2); next}; {x=$1""; printf("%s%s %s", NR==1?"":"\n", $1, $2)}; END{print ""}' input.txt | sed '/^[0-9a-f]* [0-9a-f]*$/d'
000000 0000000101 0000000201 0000000301 0000000401
000065 0000000201 0000000301 0000000401
000100 0000000101 0000000201 0000000301 0000000401
00652e 0000000201 0000000301 0000000401
008d75 0000000101 0000000201 0000000301 0000000401
010001 0000000101 0000000201 0000000301 0000000401
01008d 0000000101 0000000201 0000000301 0000000401
01a8c0 0000000101 0000000201 0000000301 0000000401
026401 0000000101 0000000201 0000000301 0000000401
0615df 0000000101 0000000201 0000000301 0000000401
07dd94 0000000101 0000000201 0000000301 0000000401
090000 0000000101 0000000201 0000000301 0000000401
15dfc7 0000000101 0000000201 0000000301 0000000401
```

---

```
FIELDWIDTHS    A white-space separated list of fieldwidths.  When set, gawk parses the input into fields of fixed width, instead of using  the  value
               of the FS variable as the field separator.
```

Comment: Sorry, I only test it on `Ubuntu`.

Comment: @kev : thanks a lot. i forgot to mention one thing. the data in the input file is in sorted order. can that be taken to advantage to get the required output. further i used this cmd on the following data :

Comment: @kev : thanks again. one more info needed. i want to use the cmd you have told above in c using system function. can you please let me know how to do that. i want to give the values of fieldwidth ie 6 and 10 here as input. i used                                                    sprintf(cmd,"gawk -v FIELDWIDTHS='%d %d' 'NR!=1 && x==$1{printf(" %s", $2); next}; {x=$1; printf("%s%s %s", NR==1?"":"\n", $1, $2)}; END{print ""}' nbyte2 | sed '/^[0-9a-f]* [0-9a-f]*$/d'",n,m); but it gives me error.

Comment: @kev : i am facing one problem in the above gawk cmd you mentioned. i used the following data `00e246b50100000f06
00e248380100002065
00e251540100000460
00e254bc01000022a9
00e25e0e0100001e4e` and used the cmd ` gawk -v FIELDWIDTHS='8 10' 'NR!=1 && x==$1{printf(" %s", $2); next}; {x=$1; printf("%s%s %s", NR==1?"":"\n", $1, $2)}; END{print ""}' inputdatafile`. But to my surprise the output comes to be `00e246b5 0100000f06
00e24838 0100002065 0100000460
00e254bc 01000022a9
00e25e0e 0100001e4e` . can you please let me know why it is so. thanks a lot again.

Comment: I'm sorry. It's a bug. You can fix it with `x==$1""` and `x=$1""`. Just add `""` after `$1` to make awk compare strings.

Answer (score 2):

You can following awk command (tested on Linux and Mac):

```
awk '{key=substr($0, 0, 6); val=substr($0, 6); arr[key]=sprintf("%s %s",val,arr[key]);}
END{for (a in arr) {split(arr[a], el, " "); if (length(el)>1) print a, arr[a]} }' file
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
000065 50000000401 50000000301 50000000201 
000100 00000000201 00000000101
```

Answer (score 2):

First, pipe your data file through this:

```
awk '{suffixLen = 10; print substr($0, 1, length($0) - suffixLen)" "substr($0, length($0) - suffixLen + 1, length($0))}'
```

The suffixLen variable is the (fixed) number of trailing characters: 2 bytes for every char = 10. This will split the input string in two fields, separated with a space.

Then pipe that through this:

```
awk '{if ($1 in values) {values[$1] = values[$1]" "$2} else {values[$1] = $1" "$2}}END{for (v in values) print values[v]}'
```

Proper sorting of the result is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

awk with `FIELDWIDTHS`  is one way to go as kev shown.

here is another way (oneliner) only with awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=""} 
  {for(i=1;i<=6;i++) x=x$i; y=$0; gsub("^"x,"",y);a[x]=a[x]?a[x]" "y:y;  x="";}
   END{for(t in a)print t" "a[t]}' yourFile
```

test with your small data block:

```
kent$  echo "0000380000000101
0000650000000201
0000650000000301
0000650000000401
0001000000000101
0001000000000201"|awk 'BEGIN{FS=""} {for(i=1;i<=6;i++) x=x$i; y=$0; gsub("^"x,"",y);a[x]=a[x]?a[x]" "y:y;  x="";}END{for(t in a)print t" "a[t]}'

000100 0000000101 0000000201
000065 0000000201 0000000301 0000000401
000038 0000000101
```